# In-app purchase sandbox server returning multiple transactions for one receipt

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, storekit

Right now, when I send a receipt to the sandbox server (sandbox.itunes.apple.com) for one transaction, I am returned information for all of the transactions associated with the Apple account. Is this expected behavior? Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, receipt contains information about all transactions that was made by app. But you should consider very important issue:

> The in-app purchase receipt for a consumable product is added to the
>   receipt when the purchase is made. It is kept in the receipt until
>   your app finishes that transaction. After that point, it is removed
>   from the receipt the next time the receipt is updated—for example,
>   when the user makes another purchase or if your app explicitly
>   refreshes the receipt.
>
> The in-app purchase receipt for a non-consumable product,
>   auto-renewable subscription, non-renewing subscription, or free
>   subscription remains in the receipt indefinitely.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Comment: When transaction state is updated it will notify an object you registered as SKPaymentTransactionObserver by calling method 
- paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: . After that you should look at transaction state and if it is "purchased" you should make purchased item available for user.

Comment: SKPaymentTransaction that was updated has plenty of information about transaction including SKPayment that has a productIdentifier and other useful properties

Comment: After your server get response from Apple you should parse whole response and update your server model accordingly. You can not get only changed part of the receipt.